# Tried validating changeset and got one error

Tags: community, deployment, change-set, cpq

While validating changeset got this error. Please help me out[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the Flexipage Quote_Record_Page1 is missing from your Change Set. You'll need to add it to the change set and try again.

Comment: Do you see "Quote Record Page" in Lightning Pages?

Comment: Yes..I am able to see.. I allready added Quote_Record_Page1 in change set list,

Comment: Thank you again #sfdcfox and #ytiq  Issue  resolved